Any limitation debugging LWC javascript in managed packages
I have some code that is working fine as source code in an org.  I put it in a managed packaged and installed the package in an org.  One LWC isn't working correctly.  I tried the Chrome developer mode and put breakpoints in the javascript but it's not hitting any of them.  I wondering if there is any limitation on debugging js from lwc if the lwc comes from a managed package.  I can't see how as the JS code is visible but I'm wonder if there is something I'm missing somewhere.

Usually, there are 2 files with the same name when you inspect LWC. Try searching again, you will find a second file with the same name. Try putting a debug point there.

I did get breakpoints to work in the javascript.  Indeed the files appeared twice and when I found the second copy and put breakpoints there, it worked.
I believe what through me is with the javascript for the lwcs is with them coming from a managed package, the file structure was a bit different than when I debugged with the source code in a development org.
